# Absence of event in Apache Flink CEP

Tags: apache-flink, complex-event-processing, flink-cep

I'm new at Apache Flink CEP and I'm struggle trying to detect a simple absence of event.

What I'm trying to detect is wheter an event of type **CurrencyEvent** with a certain id **does not occur in certain amount of time**. I would like to detect the absence of such event **every time that after 3000ms the event does not occur.**

My pattern code looks as follows:

```
Pattern<CurrencyEvent, ?> myPattern = Pattern.<Event>begin("CurrencyEvent")
        .subtype(CurrencyEvent.class)
        .where(new SimpleCondition<CurrencyEvent>() {
            @Override
            public boolean filter(CurrencyEvent currencyEvent) throws Exception {
                return currencyEvent.getId().equalsIgnoreCase("usd");
            }
        })
        .within(Time.milliseconds(3000L));
```

So now my idea is to use **timeout functions** in order to detect timeout events:

```
    DataStreamSource<Event> events = env.addSource(new TestSource(
            Arrays.asList(
                    basicCurrencyWithMivLevelEvent("EUR", 100L, Arrays.asList("1", "2"), 200D),
                    basicCurrencyWithMivLevelEvent("USD", 100L, Arrays.asList("1", "2"), 200D),
                    basicCurrencyWithMivLevelEvent("EUR", 100L, Arrays.asList("1", "2"), 200D)
            ),
            1636040364820L, // initial timestamp for the first element
            7000 // 7 seconds between each event
    ));

  PatternStream<Event> patternStream = CEP.pattern(
            events,
            (Pattern<Event, ?>) myPattern
    );

    OutputTag<Alarm> tag = new OutputTag<Alarm>("currency-timeout"){};

    PatternFlatTimeoutFunction<Event, Alarm> eventAlarmTimeoutPatternFunction = (patterns, timestamp, ctx) -> {
        System.out.println("New alarm, since after 3 seconds an event with id=usd is not detected");
        //TODO: call collect

    };


    PatternFlatSelectFunction<Event, Alarm> eventAlarmPatternSelectFunction = (patterns, ctx) -> {
        System.out.println("Select! (we can ignore it) " + patterns);
        // ignore matched events
    };

    return patternStream.flatSelect(
            tag,
            eventAlarmTimeoutPatternFunction,
            TypeInformation.of(Alarm.class),
            eventAlarmPatternSelectFunction
    );
```

My Test source is using event timestamps and watermarks, as shown as follows:

```
public class TestSource implements SourceFunction<Event> {

    private final List<Event> events;
    private final long initialTimestamp;
    private final long timeBetweenInMillis;

    public TestSource(List<Event> events, long initialTimestamp, long timeBetweenInMillis){
        this.events = events;
        this.initialTimestamp = initialTimestamp;
        this.timeBetweenInMillis = timeBetweenInMillis;


    }
    @Override
    public void run(SourceContext<Event> sourceContext) throws InterruptedException {
        long timestamp  = this.initialTimestamp;
        for(Event event: this.events){
            sourceContext.collectWithTimestamp(event, timestamp);
            sourceContext.emitWatermark(new Watermark(timestamp));
            timestamp+=this.timeBetweenInMillis;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void cancel() {

    }

}
```

I'm using **TimeCharacteristics.EventTime**.

Since the the window time (3seconds) is lower than the event time difference between every event (7 seconds), I expect to get some timeout events, but I'm getting 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A CEP `Pattern` matches a sequence of one or more events; the `within(interval)`  clause adds an additional constraint that all of the events in the sequence must occur within the specified *interval*. When partial matches time out, this can be captured in a `TimedOutPartialMatchHandler`.

In your case, since a successfully matched Pattern consists of a single event, there can be no partial matches, and a match can never time out. (Your matching sequences are always less than 3 seconds long.)

What you can do is to extend the pattern definition to include a second event, so that to match there must be a start event followed by another event within 3 seconds. When that second event is missing, then you will have a partial match that times out.

For more flexibility than what CEP offers for implementing use cases involving missing events, you can use a `KeyedProcessFunction` with timers.

Comment: Thanks for your very useful reply. Including a second event may fail if the stream has not new records for a while, so what about emitting a heartbeat into the stream every X seconds to guarantee a first event into the pattern?

Comment: Yes, heartbeats can be quite helpful in streaming applications. E.g., if you want to be able to distinguish between the source(s) being quiet, and having failed.